# I can't paste or manually type my Access Token on vs code terminal

Tags: javascript, npm, access-token, supabase

The vs code terminal won't let me write or paste the access token:

[image: The vs code terminal won't let me write or paste the access token]

I have googled and I saw [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/14oqjzk/issues_with_login/) with people having the same problem with the Access Token.

I'm following a tutorial from cooper codes on how to build a Supabase custom chatbot.

Comment: From the Reddit post you mentioned, *Edit: Typing instead of copying and pasting it solved it.*

Comment: It's probably using a [silent input](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-hide-user-input), a **very common** approach to accepting sensitive data on the terminal. Just try typing or pasting and hitting `Enter`

Comment: @Philisonstrike The silent input makes sense, i tried it and it gave me a new error
(You can generate an access token from htps://supabase.com/dashboard/account/tokens
Enter your access token:
Invalid access token format. Must be like `sbp_0102...1920`.)

Comment: @LightningMcQueen yeah but on my end it wouldnt even let me type manually. seeing a post that is 1 day old is scary af meaning there aren't much solutions to my problem bec its new :D

Comment: @Zib Why not? Try different terminals. Visual Studio Code's terminal. The terminal on Mac. Powershell. Command Prompt.

Comment: Try pasting or typing the token somewhere you _can_ see it, verify that it's correct, then copy that value and paste it into the terminal when prompted and hit `Enter`. You won't see the characters but they will be captured

Comment: Goddamn i tried CMD and it actually worked thankyou so much to the both of you, your ideas combined :D @LightningMcQueen and philonstrike <3 i appreciate the help lads.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm a life-saver, ain't I? Thanks to @Philisonstrike too, since I'm still new, I don't know what should be done here. An answer is posted or maybe the question gets closed. I think an answer that says try different terminals is not an answer.

Comment: @Zib Interesting. Do you have the same problem using Powershell directly (instead of through VS Code)? What about if you use `CMD` in VS Code (use the dropdown menu next to the `+` when adding a new terminal). I think you could add an answer below

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Yeah but both of your answers i used and worked like charm haha

Comment: @Philisonstrike unfortunately im just a newbie in coding and i haven't used powershell directly that much aside from using a youtubedownloader.py a few months back.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just open a Powershell terminal like normal (Start menu -> Powershell) and try it out. The idea is to find out if the problem is caused by VS Code's terminal emulation or if it's an actual problem with Powershell and silent inputs